# Set position absolute in css for router-outlet in Angular2

Tags: css, angular

I have a site with this base layout

```
  <nav>
    Navcontent
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I have a component that is rendered in the router outlet that I want to display on top of the Navcontent. To do this I tried with

```
.album-select-bar {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

<app-album-select-bar class="album-select-bar"></app-album-select-bar>
```

However, this places the element just below the Navcontent element. How can I make place the content of the router-outlet on top of Navcontent in Angular2?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a negative margin, to make it overflow its parent:

```
.album-select-bar {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -50px; //should equal height.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I just tried that and but this appears to hide the album-select-bar class altogether

Answer (score 0):

In your component try with

```
styles: [':host { /* your style */ }']
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#special-selectors

Comment: Thanks. However, this seems to impact the entire <main> class. I'm just interested in position a single element at z-index 100 at the top of the screen

Comment: Yaw but if you put that code into the app-album-select-bar component the style impacts only the component

Comment: I see. I tried this and cannot get it to work. Are you able to get it working in a Plunker?

Comment: I'm using the Material Design Navigation Bar as the top element outside my router outlet. Maybe the issue comes down to not being able to overwrite that?